# gitlab: How to check all the changes in a commit

Tags: gitlab

In gitlab where is the option to check all the changes in a commit w.r.t the previous commit

[image]

IN the image where can I get that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. On that screen, clicking `History` will let you see all your commits.

You can also use `Repository -> Compare` to compare branches.